# Sending form data after validating in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

Hi I'm New to web so pardon me if this is a silly question.

So I done with form validation which will be triggered after clicked on a button (`type = "button"`).
After validation i have to call php file where i can insert the data into MySql.
I did the same with submit button(`type = "submit"`) and without validation.

I don't know how to do the both one after the other.

How can I call php after validating in JavaScript?

Comment: what have you started with? I would suggest using ajax to trigger php after your javascript validation

Answer (score 0):

We will probably need to see your code to help properly, but the normal way of doing this would be to do your validation in your `onsubmit` event listener and then call `event.preventDefault();` if the validation fails, stopping the form being submitted. If the validation succeeds then the form should submit as normal.

Answer (score 0):

validation applied in both side in client side by js - you can use jquery validation " - this for user interaction only and to make sure that data is clean from any malicious code or sql injection .
but most attacker stop js from browser at first step of attack so the first validation seems no valuable so we make another one in server side also and that for real security -this can't be stop .
write more code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or if you are using jQuery use [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to sumbit data to your php page.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive what you want is:

```
var FormValidation = function () {


        // validation using icons
        var handleValidation = function() {
            // for more info visit the official plugin documentation: 
                // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

                var form = $('#form');
                var error = $('.alert-danger', form);
                var success = $('.alert-success', form);

                form.validate({
                    errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
                    errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
                    focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
                    ignore: "",  // validate all fields including form hidden input
                    rules: {



                        yourfield: {
                            minlength: 1,
                            required: true,
                            min: 0,                             
                            number: true
                        },

                    },

                    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit              
                        success.hide();
                        error.show();
                        //Metronic.scrollTo(error, -200);
                    },

                    errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
                        var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
                        icon.removeClass('fa-check').addClass("fa-warning");  
                        icon.attr("data-original-title", error.text()).tooltip({'container': 'body'});
                    },

                    highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                        $(element)
                            .closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-success").addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group   
                    },

                    unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight

                    },

                    success: function (label, element) {
                        var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // set success class to the control group
                        icon.removeClass("fa-warning").addClass("fa-check");
                    },

                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        success.show();
                        error.hide();
                        form[0].submit(); // submit the form
                    }
                });


        }



        return {
            //main function to initiate the module
            init: function () {


                handleValidation();


            }

        };

        }();
```

Answer (score 0):

// Call your javascript function on form submit i.e. onsubmit="return functionName()"

// In javascript function if fields validated then

return true;

// Else

return false;

// Use button type :

type="submit"